# Django 1.10 Postgres JSONField extract specific keys

Tags: django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

I have a Postgres based JSONField in my model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField(default=dict)
```

The JSON sample is like:

```
{
    'key1': 'val1',
    'key2': 'val2'
}
```

I have multiple objects of the model, let's say ~50.

I am trying to query for only the `key1` inside `data` and want to get a list of all the distinct values of the `key1`.

How can I do that? Please note I am using Django 1.10.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [has_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#has-key)

```
items=MyModel.objects.filter(data__has_key='key1').values_list('data',flat=True)
new_list=[]
for item in items:
    new_list.append(item['key1'])

dist_list=list(set(new_list)) #list of distinct values.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use KeyTransform for that

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(key1=KeyTransform('key1', 'data')).distinct('key1').values_list('key1', flat=True)
```